# VBA Excel IE automation: locate element by custom tag

Tags: html, excel, vba

I need to pick out an element by a custom html tag - ie, where the custom tag would be "**somecustomtag**" in the following div element

```
<div class="panel-one" somecustomtag="blue">
```

I just can't remember the sytax.  I know it's something like:

```
Set myElements = IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("div")
For Each ob in myElements
   If ob.subTag("somecustomtag") = "blue" then  ' ????????
      someStringVariable = ob.innerText
      exit for
   End If
Next ob
```

I've used this a dozen times before but can't find it any where.  What is the proper syntax for .subTag?

Answer (score 1):

In your case somecustomtag is an attribute. You will get the value of somecustomtag with the following code snippet

```
ob.getAttribute("somecustomtag")
```